# Can't change the revert option on a draggable via the "stop" event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to make a draggable list item, so it shows aditional options, like editing or deleting. My idea is, if the user drags the item more than `x` pixels and releases the item, everything will show up; otherwise, the item reverts to its original position. I'm doing this by storing the initial `left` position when the draggin starts, and then subtraction the same `left` position when it stops, so it gives me the number of pixels the draggable moved to the left, and then use that do decide if the item reverts or not.

The problem is that I've been unable to make it work both with using a function on the `revert` option, or setting up the condition inside the `stop` event.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
var move;

$(".todo-event").draggable({
    axis: "x",

    start: function (evt, ui) { move = ui.position.left; },

    stop: function (evt, ui) { move -= ui.position.left; },

    revert: function () { return (move <= 27); }
});
```

The subtraction is working, but for some reason, it looks like it's not doing the subtraction before going into the `revert` function, i.e., `move == 0` inside the `revert` function, and setting a timeout doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little testing it turns out the revert function gets called before stop one does.

Here's a working version that stores the start position on the element and compares element position to start position when revert function gets triggered.

```js
$(".todo-event").draggable({
  axis: "x",

  start: function(evt, ui) {
    console.clear();
    console.log('start')
    $(this).data('start', ui.position);
  },
  stop: function(evt, ui) {
    console.log('stop')
  },
  revert: function(evt, ui) {
    var $el=$(this),
      startL = $el.data('start').left,
      currL = $el.position().left,
      shouldRevert = Math.abs(currL - startL) <= 100;// increased threshold for demo

    console.log('revert', JSON.stringify([startL, currL, shouldRevert]));
    return shouldRevert;
  }
});
```

```css
#draggable {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div id="draggable" class="todo-event ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me</p>
</div>
```